# How to retrieve a file from the server based on a url over an Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am setting up a website where you can create certain objects called 'jobs', one of the attributes is a File's path. I got the file to be uploaded and stored in a directory with the path saved to the model,but now I want it to be broadcasted on the API ,but all I have is the path the file is on the server. How would I now go about retrieving this file on say a App with the api?

The file is already on the server and each job has a property of the corresponding file path eg. "~/Documents/InformationAboutJob.docx"

My Api currently uses Dto's for the broadcasting of the 'job' objects

My current Get method in Api

```
// GET api/values/5
public Jobdto Get(int id)
    {
        var job = _context.Jobs.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
        if (job == null)
        {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }


        return Mapper.Map<Job,Jobdto>(job);
```

The job class

```
    public class Job
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Spesifications { get; set; }
        public string ExtraInformation { get; set; }
        public string File { get; set; }
    }
```

The controller used to save the file to the model

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Job job, HttpPostedFileBase filee)
        {
            if (User.IsInRole(RoleName.CanManageJobs))
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return View("Index", job);
                }
                if (filee != null)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filee.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Documents/"), fileName);
                    filee.SaveAs(path);
                    job.File = "~/Documents/"+ fileName;
                }

                _context.Jobs.Add(job);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Manage", "Data");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Manage");
        }
```

Edit: Basically it would awnser my question if I can have the Documents in the folder be reachable by the link I broadcast over the API 
eg. www.mysite.com/Documents/Information.docx  so it can be used in an app.
But only authorized calls may be able to access it

Comment: Generally if you are exposing information about the server filesystem you are doing something wrong. Beyond that storing files on disk and paths in the database is a quick way to run into data-sync issues.

Comment: I recommend you separate your actions, one to get the Job DTO and another to download de docx file.

Comment: Thanks, but I still do not know how that separate action should look